# ¿Cómo crear un menú para panel de control cms?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

Cómo puedo imitar la plantilla de esta imagen de cms, lo he intentado de está manera pero no logro entender la forma correcta de utilizarlo en la imagen se observa un diseño mucho más complejo el menú se muestra activado con el contenido del menú o se activa el menú al hacer clic en el menú.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CSS**

```
    /* Top menu */
    .top-menu-holder {
        background-color: #4C4C4C; background-color: rgba(76,76,76,.99);
        display: block; position: fixed; text-align: center;
        left: 0; top: 0; height: 60px; line-height: 60px; width: 100%;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    /* Menu left */
    .icon-menu-holder {         
        display: block; position: fixed;
        left: 0; top: 60px; height: 100%; width: 150px;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    .icon-menu-holder.bg-icon-menu {
        display: block; position: fixed;
        background-color: #EEEEEE; 
        height: 100%; width: 60px;
    }

    .icon-holder {
        background-color: #EEEEEE;  color: #2E2E2E; font-size: 25px;
        display: block;
        height: 60px; width: 60px; line-height: 60px; text-align: center;
        transition: width .3s ease;
    }

    .icon-holder > p {
        display: none;
    }

    .icon-holder:hover {
        width: 150px;
        transition: width .3s ease;
    }

    .icon-holder:hover > p {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-right: .3rem;
    }

    .icon-holder:hover > i {
        opacity: 0;
        animation: opa .8s .2s forwards ;
    }

    @keyframes opa {
        0% {opacity: 0;}
        100% {opacity: 1;}
    }

    @media screen and (max-height: 400px) {
        /* Menu left */
        .icon-menu-holder {         
            display: block; position: fixed;
            left: 0; top: 60px; height: 100%; width: 150px; 
        }

        .icon-menu-holder.bg-icon-menu {
            display: block; position: absolute;
            background-color: none; 
            height: 100%; width: 150px;
        }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="icon-menu-holder bg-icon-menu">
  <div class="icon-holder">
    <p>Menu</p>
    <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>  

  <div class="icon-holder">
    <p>Menu</p>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="icon-holder">
    <p>Menu</p>
    <i class="fa fa-barcode" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="icon-holder">
    <p>Menu</p>
    <i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="icon-holder">
    <p>Menu</p>
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>

    <div class="icon-holder">
    <p>Admin</p>
    <i class="fa fa-user-secret" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, necesitas una clase, generalmente llamada `active` con los estilos que quieras. Por ejemplo,

```
/* Clase active de ejemplo */
.icon-holder.active {color: red;}
```

Luego, necesitas un poco de jQuery o JavaScript para asignar la clase... algo como esto, que no funciona, pero espero que sirva de inicio.

```
$('.icon-menu-holder .icon-holder').click(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
    $this.addClass('active');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Este es el resultado...

> Gracias a **@ElChiniNet** que me apuntó en la dirección correcta, ahora si, la solución funciona como se espera.

```js
$('.icon-menu-holder .icon-holder').click(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $('.icon-menu-holder .icon-holder').removeClass("active");
  if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
    $this.addClass('active');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
/* Top menu */
    .top-menu-holder {
        background-color: #4C4C4C; background-color: rgba(76,76,76,.99);
        display: block; position: fixed; text-align: center;
        left: 0; top: 0; height: 60px; line-height: 60px; width: 100%;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    /* Menu left */
    .icon-menu-holder {         
        display: block; position: fixed;
        left: 0; top: 60px; height: 100%; width: 150px;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    .icon-menu-holder.bg-icon-menu {
        display: block; position: fixed;
        background-color: #EEEEEE; 
        height: 100%; width: 60px;
    }

    .icon-holder {
        background-color: #EEEEEE;  color: #2E2E2E; font-size: 25px;
        display: block;
        height: 60px; width: 60px; line-height: 60px; text-align: center;
        transition: width .3s ease;
    }

    .icon-holder > p {
        display: none;
    }

    .icon-holder:hover {
        width: 150px;
        transition: width .3s ease;
    }

    .icon-holder:hover > p {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-right: .3rem;
    }

    .icon-holder:hover > i {
        opacity: 0;
        animation: opa .8s .2s forwards ;
    }
    
    /* Clase active de ejemplo */
    .icon-holder.active {color: red;}

    @keyframes opa {
        0% {opacity: 0;}
        100% {opacity: 1;}
    }

    @media screen and (max-height: 400px) {
        /* Menu left */
        .icon-menu-holder {         
            display: block; position: fixed;
            left: 0; top: 60px; height: 100%; width: 150px; 
        }

        .icon-menu-holder.bg-icon-menu {
            display: block; position: absolute;
            background-color: none; 
            height: 100%; width: 150px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="icon-menu-holder bg-icon-menu">
  <div class="icon-holder">
    <p>Menu 1</p>
    <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>  

  <div class="icon-holder">
    <p>Menu 2</p>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="icon-holder">
    <p>Menu 3</p>
    <i class="fa fa-barcode" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="icon-holder">
    <p>Menu 4</p>
    <i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="icon-holder">
    <p>Menu5</p>
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>

    <div class="icon-holder">
    <p>Admin</p>
    <i class="fa fa-user-secret" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Está perfecto, sólo elimina la clase `active` de todos los links antes de asignársela al link al que se le ha hecho click.

Comment: Gracias @ElChiniNet **¡Ya funciona!**.

Comment: Algo así: https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/bfohmtyj/
Es sólo añadir la línea de eliminar la clase.

Comment: ¡Perfecto! ¡eso mismo! ;)